# Fixing Overlapping Elements

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been trying to properly place an element into my page so that it doesn't obstruct the background and so that it aligns all the way to right. I've tried to recreate the scenario on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wold/L5Sv6/2/), but I couldn't recreate it exactly.

There is a lot of junk included, but to create the layout of the actual page, I had to included it. My problem is with `.login` in the style and how it is interacting with the other elements. I've tried screwing with `position`, but I haven't been able to achieve my desired result.

**Here is a screenshot of what it looks like with the problem:**

[image]

**This is what I would like:**

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Sv6/3/)? Just remove `.login`'s `width`

Comment: can you float that to the right?

Comment: @Medda86 Tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, but how do you then get it to also not obstruct the black background of the overlay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.login {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; // or what you need
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1; // i don't know if you need upper value for that
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Though the background issue is fixed, it isn't moved to the right. I think it's because it is rendering relative to its parent. Is there a way to override that?

Comment: Yes you need to put for the container, position: relative